# JavaFx. How to implement custom TableCell?

Tags: javafx, tableview, cell, tablecell

I have a `Water` object that holds reference to `Flat` object, which has values for name and last name (just `String`, not `StringProperties`). I want to create a custom `TableCell` that depending on conditions will write either full name (name + last name) or short name (last name + first letter of first name). This is the schema of my objects:

[image]

`TableView` is populated by data from `Water` object:

```
@FXML
private TableView<Water> waterTable;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Water, String> ownerColumn;
```

I tried doing custom TableCell, but I don't know how can I access data from Water object.

```
ownerColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Water,String>, TableCell<Water,String>>() {

    @Override
    public TableCell<Water, String> call(TableColumn<Water, String> param) {
        return new TableCell<Water, String>(){
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty){
                setText("Need to set a text to Water.getFlat().getName()+' '+Water.getFlat().getLastName()");
            }
        };
    }
});
```

How to change `setText` line, so that it will get info from `Water` object that will be assigned for this row?

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
@FXML
private TableView<Water> waterTable;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Water, Flat> ownerColumn;


// and setCellFactory
ownerColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Water,Flat>, TableCell<Water,Flat>>() {

    @Override
    public TableCell<Water, Flat> call(TableColumn<Water, Flat> param) {
        return new TableCell<Water, Flat>(){
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Flat item, boolean empty){
                setText(item.getOwnerName()+" "+item.getOwnerLastName());
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Surely if the data you want is in the `flat` property of `Water`, then this should be a `TableColumn<Water, Flat>`, not a `TableColumn<Water, String>`? Can you include the cell value factory you are using?

Comment: That's everything I have so far. Changing from `String` to `Flat` is not a problem, but how can I access it from `updateItem` method? Should `String item` be replaced with `Flat item` there as well?

Comment: I learned that `setCellValueFactory` is only for `ObservableProprerties`. But since I do not use them in my objects, I used `setCellFactory` instead.

Comment: Yes, change the type of the item. It won't let you compile if you don't. As for the different factories, you will need both. It sounds like you need  to read a basic tutorial on how table views work. [This one](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part2/) is popular. The difference between the different factories is explained [here](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-cell-renderer/).

Comment: I read it before, but there everywhere are used `ObservableProperties` to update view. I really don't need view to be updated, since there won't be any modifications happening to object. So I didn't create `ObservableProperties` when creating my objects. Objects are pretty big, so it will take me a while to rewrite all of them to `ObservableProperties`. So I was wondering if I can make `TableView` work using just simple `String` values from my objects?

Comment: The cell value factory just needs to return an `ObservableValue`, you don't necessarily need one in the model. Just create a property directly in the factory.

Comment: Your updated code will yield a `NullPointerException` for empty cells. You need to handle the case where the `updateItem` is called for a cell that is empty.

Comment: thanks fabian, I'll make sure to add it to code.

Comment: James_D, based on tutorial that you mentioned they use `birthdayColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().birthdayProperty()); ` but I don't have a `Properties` in my model, so I'm not sure how to write one for my table, especially since what will be written is defined in `setCellFactory`. `ownerColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getFlat());`

Comment: Why not just `ownerColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue().getFlat()));` ???

Comment: As well as handling empty cells, your cell factory needs to call the superclass method. Again, refer to the tutorial (or just the Javadocs).

Comment: it works!))))))